I forgot my phones passcode and got locked out from my iPhone 13 and forgot my iCloud password and lost recovery key how can I reset my Apple ID?
How can I recover my recovery key from my iCloud account? I locked myself out from my iPhone 13 and recently found my iPhone 8 that I was still logged into. Unfortunately it doesn’t allow me to make any changes on my Apple ID or receive any emails on iCloud. Called Apple and they pretty much said I’m ’d. There’s a recommendation for authkitui.service for saved passwords but I never installed that?

So you don't have any record of any passwords linked to your accounts? What about the security questions?

Unfortunately, there is no way I know of to resolve this situation. There is no way for Apple to tell the difference between someone who legitimately lost or forgot all this information from a person who simply stole a device. If you did lose all of your information, had to buy a new phone and set up a new AppleID, that truly stinks - but if you were a person who lost their phone, you would definitely not want Apple helping the person who found it to access your information and account data.
